# How do I make my code loop through this array?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a color changer, I want the program to loop through the array, change the color one by one with every click, then update the color-code class to the name of the array, I haven't implemented this yet because I want to tackle this initial problem first. So far, It only changes the color to the last index.

```
const colorArray = ["blue", "green", "red", "orange", "violet", "indigo", "yellow", "white", "pink", "black"];

function changeColor() {
    const body = document.querySelector('body');
    const bodyColor = body.style.backgroundColor;
    const colorCode = document.querySelector('color-code');
    const button = document.querySelector('button');

    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        for(let i = 0; i < colorArray.length; i++) {
            body.style.backgroundColor = colorArray[i];
        }
    

    })
}

changeColor();
```

I tried using a for loop, I'm not quite sure it's the right way to go.

Comment: "I tried using a for loop, I'm not quite sure it's the right way to go" it isn't. You want to have a counter that you increment every click and set the background color to `colorArray[i]`. You don't need any loops. Don't forget to check if the counter gets incremented past the end of the array!

Comment: You need to maintain state across clicks so you can determine the next color. Example [here](https://typedarray.org/javascript-change-button-color-on-click/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *is* looping through the array.  The result is that the last value remains set.

It sounds like you *don't* want to loop through the array, but rather want to keep track of the current index of the array and use the "next" one on each click.  Something like this:

```
const colorArray = ["blue", "green", "red", "orange", "violet", "indigo", "yellow", "white", "pink", "black"];
let currentIndex = 0;

const body = document.querySelector('body');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

function changeColor() {
  // set the color to the current array index, and increment the index
  body.style.backgroundColor = colorArray[currentIndex++];

  // if the current index exceeds the array, reset it
  if (currentIndex >= colorArray.length) {
    currentIndex = 0;
  }
}

button.addEventListener('click', changeColor)

changeColor();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have had a headache trying to figure this out. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

As understood you need to change new color on every click that means initially first color of the array is visible then on click second color and so on, assuming the same here is the code that can be used to achieve this

```
const colorArray = ["blue", "green", "red", "orange", "violet", "indigo", "yellow", "white", "pink", "black"];
const colorCounter = 0
body.style.backgroundColor = colorArray[colorCounter]

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    changeColor();
})

function changeColor() {
    colorCounter++
    if(colorCounter > colorArray.length - 1){
        colorCounter = 0
    }
    const body = document.querySelector('body');
    body.style.backgroundColor = colorArray[colorCounter]
}
```

Above code will use first value of array as initial color and then on every button click a counter increment will happen and color will be change to next value of the array, also if whole array is iterated the counter will reset and again first color will set

Comment: @phuzi already added that, well thanks

Comment: Thank you guys so much, you have been more than helpful!